# Stale Element Exception, Element not Clickable,Element Click Intercepted & No Such Element error displayed Alternately by same element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testautomationfx

I am trying to select multiple filers available in https://www.jabong.com/find/men's-black-jeans using Automation(Firefox).

However, after selecting the first option (Gender), I am unable to proceed.

I faced the Element click intercepted and tried Fluent Wait which lead to Stale Element Exception.

If I remove the Fluent wait or use implicit wait, I sometimes get the Element found exception.

To add to the confusion, sometimes the code runs properly without any wait and am able to select multiple options, but that is rare

```
 public void case9() {
     driver.get("https://www.jabong.com/");
      WebElement SearchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search\"]"));
      SearchBox.sendKeys("men's black jeans");
      Actions actn = new Actions (driver);
      actn.sendKeys(SearchBox, Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(34, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"allFilterPopupTop\"]")).click();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(34, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[1]/div/section/section[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/label[1]/div/input")).click();


      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Brand\"]")).click();
      WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver,61);
      WebElement brand1 = 
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath for element"));
      wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(brand1));
      brand1.click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath for element")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"Global_Size\"]")).click();
      WebElement Size = 
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath for element")); 
      wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(Size));
      Size.click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Fit\"]")).click();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(61, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath for element")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Fade\"]")).click();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(61, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
      [@id=\"applyFIlters\"]")).click();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and this code works fine.

```
driver.get("https://www.jabong.com/");
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#search"));
        searchBox.sendKeys("men's black jeans");
        WebElement searchIcon = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#top-search-input > div.search-containter > span"));
        searchIcon.click();
        WebElement firstCheckBox = driver.findElement(By.id("boys"));
        firstCheckBox.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Arun Nair, Choosing Gender is not an issue.Please try and select some options from all/most of the categories and then apply filter. Select in atleast 5-6 categories

Comment: For Ex Brand,size,Fade,Waist etc